# Why doesn't F# infer the record type when updating a record?

Tags: f#, record

This example code:

```
type recordA = { X: string; }
type recordB = { X: string; }

let modifyX newX record = { record with X = newX }

let modifiedRecordA = {recordA.X = "X"} |> modifyX "X2" 
let modifiedRecordB = {recordB.X = "X"} |> modifyX "X2"
```

Results in:

```
  let modifyX newX record = { record with X = newX }
  --------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(4,27): warning FS0667: The field labels and expected type of this record expression or pattern do not uniquely determine a corresponding record type

  let modifiedRecordA = {recordA.X = "X"} |> modifyX "X2" 
  -------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(6,44): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    recordA -> 'a    
but given a
    recordB -> recordB    
The type 'recordA' does not match the type 'recordB'
```

My expectation is that modifiedRecordA ends up equivalent to { recordA.X = "X2" } and modifiedRecordB ends up equivalent to { recordB.X = "X2" }, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

1. Why doesn't this just infer and return the appropriate record type based on the parameter type?
2. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Comment: Records don't really do inheritance.  It may be possible to do this with some inline magic, but you probably want to rethink your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inline magic required to make this work is based on overload resolution combined with statically resolved [member constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx). Overloads defined as [operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx) avoid the need to spell out explicit constraints.

```
type Foo = Foo with
    static member ($) (Foo, record) = fun newX -> { record with recordA.X = newX }
    static member ($) (Foo, record) = fun newX -> { record with recordB.X = newX }

let inline modifyX newX record = (Foo $ record) newX

let modifiedRecordA = {recordA.X = "X"} |> modifyX "X2" 
let modifiedRecordB = {recordB.X = "X"} |> modifyX "X2"
```

Constructs which pass types for which no overload exists do not compile.

```
type recordC = { X: string; }
let modifiedRecordC = {recordC.X = "X"} |> modifyX "X2" 
// Error    No overloads match for method 'op_Dollar' ...
// Possible overload ... The type 'recordC' is not compatible with the type 'recordB'
// Possible overload ... The type 'recordC' is not compatible with the type 'recordA'
```

This is not really intended for actual use. Heed the advise and explore if other approaches are better suited to your problem.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was too lazy to do!

Answer (score 3):

the function `modifyX` is incorrect. You may not use the term `X` in the definition and have that `X` refer to different fields.

Section 6.3.6 of the F# spec

> Each field label must resolve to a field Fi in a single record type R, all of whose fields are accessible.

By passing `recordA` and `recordB` to `modifyX` the `X` is not uniquely determined to be a field of a single type.

What you actually want is probably a polymorphic property member inherited through an interface, not a set of record types with a common member name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler is inferring the type of `modifyX` based on usage.  My understanding is that this proceeds from the bottom up, so the type is inferred to be `val modifyX : newX:string -> record:recordB -> recordB`.  This, of course, then results in a type error when attempting to use this with a record of type `recordA`.  The warning is telling you that, although its picking a type, there is another type with the same fields, so all the compiler can do is make its best guess at which type you meant.  It might be possible to achieve what you're trying to do with inline functions, but I'm not sure how that might work offhand.